# PythonAnywhere: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I am `deploying` a project on `PythonAnywhere`. I am using `sqlite` database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase.db',
    }
}
```

When `makemigrations` starts, the file `mydatabase.db` is created (its size is 0 bytes) in root of the project, but I get an error - `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: ...`

Comment: ```makemigrations``` just create migration files. You need run ```migrate``` to apply migrations to your database. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) for details.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: ```... no such table: ...``` what table? Please, specify.

Comment: `app_prediction`

Comment: So you have ```app``` application in your project, and model ```Prediction``` in it. When you run ```./manage.py makemigrations``` or ```./manage.py migrate``` then you see this error. Right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200860/discussion-between-yevhenii-m-and-pythoner).

Answer (score 1):

*The error was due to my carelessness.*

In django, `views.py` is performed before `migrations`. There was a line that ran a `database query`. Since the `database` was empty on the server, and the script was already executing a request to it, it is obvious that during the `migrations` I received this error.

It was enough just to *delete / comment* out the database request.